# Why does an xUnit Fact type test without assertions always passes?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

Sample:

```cs
[Fact]
public void FooTest(){

}
```

Result in VS2015:
Test Passed

I'm using xUnit NuGet v2.4.1 in a .NET 4.6 Framework C# project.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? There's no *failing* assertion.

Comment: Tests will only fail with exceptions. They are the circuit breaker. Any test that runs to completion without any exception is considered a passing test. within all assertions, if it fails it throws an exception that is caught by the test runner to indicate that the test failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A test fails if an assertion fails. Equivalently, a test passes if every assertion succeeds.  Let's be more precise and mathematical:

- If the number of failures is not zero, the test fails.
- If the number of assertions is equal to the number of successful assertions, the test passes.

In your test case the number of failures is zero, and the number of successes is equal to the number of assertions; both are equal to zero.

The rule is not "every assertion must succeed and there must be at least one assertion". The rule is just "every assertion must succeed" and that condition is met.

Comment: _"every assertion must succeed and there must be at least one assertion"_ - I wish it were, though - so that we can more easily detect bugs within the tests themselves. There's nothing worse than a false-pass test result - that's how bugs end-up shipping into production (...as I found out this morning).